# Print the value from stored procedure in yii2

Tags: stored-procedures, yii2, resultset

I want print the result of stored procedure that I execute.

This is the code that I've tried:

```
    public function actionGetdata($tranId) {
    $model = new ReceivedGoodsDetail();
    // $model = $this->findModel($tranId);
    $connection = \Yii::$app->db;
    $transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();

    //set nilai default
    $model->ID_Received_Goods = $tranId;

    if ($model->validate()) {
        $connection = Yii::$app->db;
        $command = $connection->createCommand('{call usp_T_Sales_Inventory_Detail#SelectData(:ID_Received_Goods)}');

        $ID_Received_Goods = $model->ID_Received_Goods;
        $command->bindParam(":ID_Received_Goods", $ID_Received_Goods, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $isSuccess = 0;
        if ($command->execute()) {
            $transaction->commit();
            $isSuccess = 1;
        } else {
            $transaction->rollBack();
            $isSuccess = 0;
        }
        return [
            'data' => $isSuccess
        ];
    } else {
        $isSuccess = 0;

        return [
            'data' => $isSuccess,
            'error' => $model->getErrors(),
        ];
    }
}
```

when I tried this in RESTClient the result is

```
<response>
<data>1</data>
</response>
```

while I want the result will show the result of

```
select * 
from T_Received_Goods_Detail 
where ID_Received_Goods = 'RG/1608/11'
```

Please help.

Comment: Why it will show the result of `select * from T_Received_Goods_Detail where ID_Received_Goods='RG/1608/11'` When you are setting `$isSuccess = 1;` & `$isSuccess = 0;` and returning `'data' => $isSuccess,`. So, it will print either `1` or `0`. It's good that it is printing `1`. Means, it is executing your query.

Comment: I want to see the result from execute that query,
for example:

    `<response>
<item>
<ID_Received_Goods>RG/1607/1</ID_Received_Goods>
<ID_Detail_Received_Goods>158</ID_Detail_Received_Goods>
<ID_Item>ITEM-0002</ID_Item>
<Qty>200</Qty>
<insert_user>admin</insert_user>
<insert_date>2016-07-28 10:36:50.910</insert_date>
<update_user>admin</update_user>
<update_date>2016-07-28 10:36:50.910</update_date>
</item>

<response>`

Comment: You want I Know. But, where have you written any code for getting selected data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of returning the value of `$isSuccess` you could run your query instead and return the result in case the operation was successful.

In pseudo code:

```
if ($isSucces) {
    $data = [result of query "select * from T_Received_Goods_Detail where ..."];
    return [
            'data' => $data
        ];
}
```

Make sure `$data` is a plain Array and the REST interface will output a valid response for you.